# Name does not exist (access to the id)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

**short: Can I somehow access the ID="imgStackExample"**

I try to give the user a visual feedback (eg. icon in the head of the table) it throws "*name does not exist in current context*". I need the ID of the control element to change the Visible prop or the CssClass.

```
<asp:GridView
            ID="GridExample"
            runat="server"
            <Columns>                 
                <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="StackExample">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnStackExample" runat="server" Text="StackExample" OnClick="onChangeHandler" ></asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:Image ID="imgStackExample" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/330-sort-alpha-desc.svg"/>
                        <br />    
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStackExample" runat="server" OnTextChanged="onChangeHandler" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>                                             
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%#Eval("StackExample") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Here the code from the onChangeHandler

```
 if (sender is LinkButton)
    {
        LinkButton lBtn = (LinkButton)sender;

        switch (lBtn.ID)
        {
            case "lbtnStackExample":
                //some code
                imgStackExample.Visible = true;//this line here is important
                //some code
```

I can not access ID="imgStackExample" in the .cs file. If I use `imgStackExample.Visible = true;` it throws the error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but in case you need to handle a button click coming from a `GridView`, you can use the `RowCommand` and there you can extract the index, which you need to refer to the image control. An example can be found from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Edit**

You have updated the question, so I update my answer, although, the answer can still be found from the link provided.
The image does not indeed exist in the context you are trying to reference to it. In order to refer to a control inside the gridview you will have to find it using an index you can pass using a commandArgument from a known sender, in this case the button. As states in the example I provided:

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
// Retrieve the row that contains the button clicked 
// by the user from the Rows collection.
 GridViewRow row = ProductsGridView.Rows[index];
```

Then you can have access to the controls inside the GridView, like

```
Label listPriceTextBox = (Label)row.FindControl("PriceLabel");
```

This of course presumes you have added the index as a commandargument to your button or you can get the index from the id of the button.

Comment: Im sorry I will edit my initial post and try to improve in asking questions. But its not about triggering actions.

Comment: I have edited my answer, but it is pretty much the same and the link I provided will still solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

to access `templatefield` inside `gridview` follow code below

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in grd.Rows)
    {
        var txt = row.FindControl("txtStackExample") as TextBox;
         if (txt != null)
         {
           // do something with your textbox
         }
     }
```

to create a `event` against `button` use `RowCommand event` of gridview.

```
 protected void GridExample_RowCommand(object sender,GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.CommandName == "lbtnStackExample")
   {
    LinkButton lnkbtn = (LinkButton)e.CommandSource;
    string Id= lnkbtn.CommandArgument;
  // write link button click event code here
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I guess I just did not write what I actually wanted. If you could have a look at the updated Question.